# how to prevent popup to disappear in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a popup in which I made a toggle with the help of pure CSS. Now if I run The popup and move my mouse at the uppermost or the lowermost part of the window the popup start disappear. I am using 0% JAVASCRIPT inside my popup code and can't find what was a reason in the code.

**here is the issue:**https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Mtm.jpg

focus on the mouse cursor! Also, I am looking  a way to open a popup at the page load without js

**POPUP code:**

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target,.modalDialog:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>#__spookyPopup {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.profile_container {
  height: 160px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #;
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile_div {
  height: 120px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.head_div {
  min-height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}



.priv_cont {
  height: 90px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #;
  display: inline-block;
}

.priv_head {
  height: 60px;
  width: 330px;
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-top:15px;
  background: #;

  
}




.clicker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: ;
  color: #FFF;
}

.clicker:hover{border-bottom: 2px solid red ;
}


#click_styling
{
margin-top:20px;
height: 50px;
 width: 197px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;color:#000;
 line-height:50px;
 text-decoration:none;
 cursor:default;"

}
.clicker.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.hiddendiv {
  height: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}


.social {
  height: 160px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}

.social_link {
  height: 60px;
  width: 330px;
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-top:15px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  
}


.hiddendiv.nr2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#showdiv1:target~div a[href="#showdiv1"],
#showdiv2:target~div a[href="#showdiv2"] {
  display: none;
}

#showdiv1:target~div a[href="#hidediv1"],
#showdiv2:target~div a[href="#hidediv2"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

#showdiv1:target~div .hiddendiv.nr1,
#showdiv2:target~div .hiddendiv.nr2 {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#__spooky_auth_popup">Open Modal</a>

<div id="__spooky_auth_popup" class="modalDialog">
  <div id="__spookyPopup">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>



    <div class="profile_container">

      <div class="profile_div"></div>
    </div>
 
 
    <div class="head_div">
      <p style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;
          font-size:25px;color:#8d8686;">
        <I>Hey, please login to access your private content.</I>
      </p>
    </div>



     <div id="showdiv1"></div>
    <div id="showdiv2"></div>

    <div>
      <a href="#showdiv1" class="clicker "  id="click_styling" tabindex="1">SOCIAL</a>
     <a href="#hidediv1" class="clicker hidden "  id="click_styling" tabindex="1">SOCIAL</a>

     <a href="#showdiv2" class="clicker "  id="click_styling" tabindex="2">MANUAL</a>
     <a href="#hidediv2" class="clicker hidden "  id="click_styling" tabindex="2">MANUAL</a>

     <div class="hiddendiv nr1">
     
       <div class="social">
       <div class="social_link"> 
       
         <div data-html="allow" >
            <iframe  id="iFrame1"  style="border: 0px;  display: block" height="400" class="spoooky-auth" src="https://api.spooo.ky/auth/facebook" border="0"></iframe>
         </div>
           <!-- End of facebook button -->
       
       </div>
       <div class="social_link">

         <!-- Optional: Linkedin button starts here -->
         <div data-html="allow" >
          <iframe style="border: 0px;  display: inline-block" class="spoooky-auth" src="https://api.spooo.ky/auth/linkedin" border="0"></iframe>
         </div>
         <!-- End of linkedin button -->


       </div>
     </div>
     
     </div>
     <div class="hiddendiv nr2">y</div>
   
      </div>
   
   <div class="priv_cont">
   
     <div class="priv_head"><p style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;font-size:18px;color:#000;">
      <I>By continuing to the content you agree with the <a href="#"  style="color:#000;">cookie</a> 
      and <a href="#"  style="color:#000;">privacy</a> policies.</I> </p>
     </div>
   
   </div>
```

Any Idea?what was the issue? 
Any input is apprecheated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your modalDialog box by default has an opacity of zero.  Upon hovering it the opacity goes to one.  Everything else is also nested in this div that upon no longer hovering the div, it all disappears.

```
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target,.modalDialog:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```